# отправка письма на почту php

Tags: php, ajax

Имеется стандартная **форма**:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name"> 
  <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
</form>
```

**ajax запрос**:

```
var str = form.serialize();
$.ajax({
        url: 'contacts.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: str
       }).done(function(msg) {

            if (msg === "OK") {
              console.log('сообщение отправлено');
              $(".res").html(res);
            } else {
              $(".res").html(msg);
            }

          }).always(function() {
            ...
          });
    });
```

И есть сам **contacts.php**:

```
<?php

    define("CONTACT_FORM", 'myEmail@gmail.com');    

        $subject = 'Заявка';

        $name  = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
        $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
        $email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
        $msg   = stripslashes($_POST['msg']);

        $error = '';    

        $message = '
            <html>
                    <head>
                            <title>Заявка</title>
                            <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                            <p>Имя     : '.$name.'</p>  
                            <p>Email   : '.$email.'</p>
                            <p>Phone   : '.$phone.'</p>
                            <p>Message : '.$msg.'</p>
                    </body>
            </html>';


        $mail = mail(CONTACT_FORM, $subject, $message,
            "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
            ."From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
            ."Reply-To: ".$email."\r\n"
            ."Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
            ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail){
            echo "OK";
        }   
?>
```

где `'myEmail@gmail.com'` - адрес куда должны приходить письма.

Никаких ошибок нет пишет что все отлично отправлено (js срабатывает *"OK"* от php приходит в любом случае).

Если в поле формы введено `myEmail@gmail.com` то письма приходят, а если в поле формы введено `Vasya@mail.ru` (или любой другой почтовый адрес) - письма просто не приходят.

**Вопрос:** почему при заполнении формы и отправке, письмо приходит на почту только если адрес email в форме (`<input type="text" name="email" id="email" >`) совпадает с `define("CONTACT_FORM", 'myEmail@gmail.com');`? Как можно исправить .php?

Comment: покажите код формы и как Вы формируете значение `str`. И что говорят логи?

Comment: добавила в вопрос форму, `str`. Никаких ошибок нет пишет что все отлично отправлено. Письма от `myEmail@gmail.com` на `myEmail@gmail.com` - приходят, а от `Vasya@mail.ru` на `myEmail@gmail.com` - просто не приходят.

Comment: Прямо чертовщина какая-то (

Comment: а почему они должны приходить от Vasya@mail.ru  обычно письма с сайта отправляются либо с сервера пхп. либо с почтового но с 1 адреса типа request@site.ru, что бы отправить письма с какого либо почтового адреса вроде как нужно подлючиться к тому почтовому серверу который обслуживает этот адрес

Comment: @BroouzerKing, не правильно сформировала вопрос), не C  , а если введен в поле формы любой другой email.

Comment: У вас письмо спам-фильтром блокируется.

Comment: В спаме тоже ничего нет.

Comment: Замените `."From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"` на `."From: ".$name." <".CONTACT_FORM.">\r\n"` и будет вам счастье.

Comment: @Visman, СПАСИБО!!! Заработало!! )))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему гугл (а возможно и не он) пропускает письма от сторонних серверов с указанием отправителя равного получателю, я не знаю.

Решение из моего комментария:

Заменить строку кода

```
."From: ".$name." <".$email.">\r\n"
```

на

```
."From: ".$name." <".CONTACT_FORM.">\r\n"
```

чтобы отправитель равнялся получателю всегда.

**P.S.** Ответ на такие письма генерируется по кнопке **Ответить** в почтовом клиенте. При этом в адрес получателя ответа ставятся данные из заголовка `Reply-To:`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!)

Answer (score 3):

Я обычно использую такую конструкцию для отправки сообщения

```
$field_email = 'request@site.ru';// откуда будут слаться письма

$mail_to = 'куда отправлять (в вашем случае myEmail@gmail.com)';
$subject = 'тема письма';

$body_message = '
<html>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <body> 
        <p>
            Имя: '.$name.'<br>
            Email: '.$email.'<br>
            Номер телефона: '.$phone.'<br>
            Текст: '.$summary.'
        </p> 
    </body> 
</html>';

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status=mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);
```

Comment: все равно та же проблема (